# How to generate a variable of months between given start and end month

Tags: sql, variables

I need to generate a list of months into a variable in a text-based format, based on a given Start- and End-Month, to be used as an IN clause for a WHERE stement.

The months are formatted as 2023M1 to 2023M12, 2024M1 to 2023M12, etc., and the start/end months can cross years,but it will never be more than 1 year ahead.

e.g. Start = 2023M7 will always have an End = 2024M7 or less.

I already have the variable named @ValidTimes to hold the output, to be used as WHERE Time IN @ValidTimes

e.g. If StartMonth = 2023M9 and EndMonth = 2024M3,
I need @ValidTimes to be
('2023M9','2023M10','2023M11','2023M12','2024M1','2024M2')

The start and end months could be anything, and there is no list of months in a table anywhere, so I need to generate them on the fly.

Thanks

Comment: "The start and end months could be anything, and there is no list of months in a table anywhere, so I need to generate them on the fly." - Is there anything preventing you from creating your own table holding all months? This sounds like an obvious candidate for a date or month dimension-like table. That way you can easily join to the table and retrieve the values from there, rather than executing code to calculate them all the time.

Comment: Hi Schmitz.  No, I cannot add a table to this database, but if I can generate the variable, I can write the dynamic SQL around it.  Thanks